# One file .html with css style and images inside

Tags: html, css, image

I have the index.html file, where iside I put CSS as inline style. I'd also have inside links to images, not to path to images. Finally, I'd like to have index.html file which will contains evrything inside as one file. How can I make not to get images from computer path but have a links to my images?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your question is not clear at all... Could you please provide an example or something ?

Comment: you need to be more specific - but if you want to use an URL as image source - then you just write <img src="ImageUrlHere" alt="internetimage">

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are seeking to build one huge file "index.html" which contains all the information needed to display what you want to display.

Think that this is something extremely unusual. Why would you need that? Probably there are better ways to achieve what you want to achieve.

If you really want to go for it, ideas that come to mind are:
* use simple graphics in form of .SVG images, these can be described with the HTML SVG tag
* use compiled HTML (.CHM) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) - but not for the web...

Answer (score 0):

when u want to call image from outside then call like below when you use http in url it will never look for local file path

```
     <img src="http://www.domainname.com/yourimage.png" alt="image">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a folder like `images` where is your `index.html` then put your all images in `images folder` & link your images like this

```
<img src="images/logo.png" />
```

This is folder path not from your computer, When you will upload it then this path will be automatically global

or you can use direct link from server like this:

```
 <img src="https://www.example.com/logo.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to include all files relationally in a /images folder however if you need a one file solution then you could encode the images in base64 and use that in the `src=""`